# Voltage and current sensing hardware on chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I have an external R C circuit excited by a step voltage source ( to be present inside a chip) to find the values of components R and C through transient analysis. Since we need to know voltage and current across the network to achieve this purpose, I am wondering how can we design a hardware using MOSFET and other passive components (may be through a differential or instrumentation amplifier), which will be present inside the same integrated chip, to measure voltage and current across the network at different instants of time. Is this done before to have the voltage and current measuring hardware in an integrated circuit? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Value range expected, spectrum and layout issues? Yes some voltage regulators do this.

Comment: Voltage range between -10 to +10 volt and current from 10uA to 1mA.

Comment: Rise time limit and real issues why you need to do this without mentioning impedance matching?

Comment: This RC network which I mentioned is an electrode implanted for biomedical stimulation inside the body, we need to find R and C values to track the electrode voltage closely for constant current stimulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [Howland](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMZICYaoOyYMxgByoBsAnCZiHPpZRHAKYC0iiAUAIYipxFJEQ4i1RPxDCEzBMlgwQOSDkVgiLVDnyIALKh1yFixNkz44YQaXyakMsKwDucoXwFOSvWw8HDRXrqiu2AE5cPH5WvjoBcrCswdy8bo7UiXQxcaGJWlYptDCxSJpWkSG8xQIxDvFImKWhZawASgXZvFkgmtQQEJoQjAhdUHCsAObNYWNVXfYlIIlVbR4zxVVYqOD5K5hrVThwaxDoeQDO0UVbp3J74EggAGbsADZH9NM7V3jhV7ajb9uh6lFFps1h8uOdbAAPJD4ChECioQwgTDdLhWBpsKF4CBwuR4JEo-wgBqoVhQxAmEIkLiIBDENZFNE4UlcEjUbhUnCoNlEemoomaZnk8LoPwctTtPkPAD27AAJqwpUhECAiFEeuQuJB%20tAzIhuNc1iw5KwgA) current source with all R vale’s scaled up for safe current limiting such that the Op Amp saturates and its output reflects your impedance ratio.

Inputs for Vref and ground may be swapped for single supply if you wish.